# Realm Results array sorted by primary key is not coming out actually sorted

Tags: ios, realm

I've got a Realm db containing objects, the primary key is a string containing numbers i.e.

```
@objc public class Caller : Object
{
    @objc dynamic var number                    = ""


    ...

    override public static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "number"
    }
```

If I try to retrieve the objects sorted by the key they are not coming out in order i.e.

```
let results = realm.objects(Caller.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "number")
```

If the db contains 3 objects with values for number of 12037366517, 12037600287, 67725082. Then if I iterate through results and log "number" the results are:

```
12037366517
12037600287
67725082
```

Why are they not coming out in sorted order?

Comment: What is the type of the `number` property?

Comment: @wvteijlingen. String, I updated the question to show more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour if `number` is a string. When sorting strings in ascending order, it is sorted in lexicographical order. So the character "3" comes after "2", which comes after "1" etc. Your results are sorted correctly, just not as you expected it.

You can fix this by sorting on an actual numeric value. The best way would be to actually store the numbers as integers instead of strings. If that is not possible, you will have to manually sort, but I think that will be less performant.

```
let results = realm.objects(Caller.self).sorted { (a, b) -> Bool in
  if let aInt = Int(a), let bInt = Int(b) {
    return aInt < bInt
  }
  return false
}
```

Comment: If I do that the results are: 67725082, 12037600287, 12037366517. So not numerically ascending as 12037600287 is the largest number but isn't coming last.

Comment: You are right, inverting the sort order doesn't work. You have to sort on a numerical value instead. I updated my answer.

Comment: My app is already released, if I change from strings to some integral type I'll have to migrate the DB. I can see options to rename a property during migration, but can't see one to change the type, is that possible?

Comment: You should be able to use a migration and manually populate the new fields. See: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#updating-values

Comment: @Gruntcakes This is a great answer and ultimately moving your data over to Int's is the best solution. Another option if you want to stick with strings is to pad the numbers so they are all the *same length* which will make them sort correctly. So 67725082 would be 00067725082 which will make it come before 12037600287.